# RVM Ruby 1.8.6 problem with RMagick

Tags: ruby, rmagick, rvm

I have Mac OS X 10.6.2 with default Ruby 1.8.7. I installed Ruby 1.8.6 thourgh RVM (rvm install 1.8.6). While I run my tests with Ruby 1.8.6 I get error:

dyld: NSLinkModule() error
dyld: Symbol not found: _DestroyConstitute
  Referenced from: /Users/snowak/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p383/gems/rmagick-2.12.2/lib/RMagick2.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/snowak/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p383/gems/rmagick-2.12.2/lib/RMagick2.bundle
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (): [/Users/snowak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p383/...]

And test suite ends up.
What is wrong with this Ruby instalation? In Ruby 1.8.7 all test are passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of ImageMagick do you have installed?  If you have 6.5.7 or higher installed, you need to have 2.13 or higher of rmagick

http://rubyforge.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=46689&forum_id=32

At the time I'm writing this, I couldn't install 2.13 via the gem command, only 2.12.2.  So just download the gem directly and install the file:

```
wget http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/68155/rmagick-2.13.0.gem
gem install rmagick-2.13.0.gem
```